# Type casting in TPC inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, casting, linq-to-entities, entity-relationship

I have several products like HotelProduct, FlightProduct ... which derived from BaseProduct class. The table of these products will be generated in TPC manner in database. There is OrderLine class which has a BaseProduct.
[image]

My problem is when i select an OrderLine with related product i don't know how cast BaseProduct to derived product. for example i have this query:

```
var order = (from odr in _context.Orders
        join orderLine in _context.OrderLines on odr.Id equals orderLine.OrderId
        join hotel in _context.Products.OfType<HotelProduct>() on orderLine.ProductId equals hotel.Id
        where odr.UserId == userId && odr.Id == orderId
        orderby odr.OrderDate descending
        select odr).SingleOrDefault();
```

In OrderLine i have BaseProduct properties not properties of HotelProduct. Is there any way to cast BaseProduct to derived class in OrderLine or any other solutions ?

Comment: Isn't it automatically created as derived instance ?

Comment: No it just create base class even when I use `OfType`.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to do isn't possible with the TPC strategy. Consider the `ProductId` property on `OrderLine`: is it an FK to the HotelProduct table or the FlightProduct table? It can only be one, so the `Product` property can only be mapped to an association to either `HotelProduct` or `FlightProduct`.

You have at least two alternatives:

- Replace the `ProductId`/`Product` properties with `HotelProduct`/`HotelProductId` *and* `FlightProduct`/`FlightProductId` properties on OrderLine, so you can navigate to the kind of product you want; or,
- Switch to a Table Per Type strategy, so the `HotelProduct` and `FlightProduct` tables each have a 1-0,1 relationship with a third Product table which has a relationship with the OrderLine table.

Comment: Yes on solution is using HotelProduct and FlightProduct in OrderLine but for each product I have to add another product property to OrderLine and at the end there are lots of product properties in OrderLine. And the reason of I do not use TPT is there will be lots of product in that table and cost of join will be to high but in this case I'm not really sure about it and if I'm wrong make me clear about it.

Comment: @MohsenEsmailpour, a join across linked primary keys is going to be extremely fast. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, is there any resource on this subject for more understanding ?